# concurrent connection limit on Youtube live embedded

Tags: wordpress, youtube

I wonder if there is a limit on concurrent connections of youtube live embed.
Let's say 10,000 visitors coming to my website to watch the embedded youtube live stream.
I'm using video widget of Elementor in my wordpress website to embed the youtube live, I just need to input the youtube link, the live video will display. I'm not sure if the widget uses any api for this.

Will the video stop displaying on my website if viewers exceeds a number?